# Storing form values as array of objects in local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Every time I add a new object to the array, it overrides the old values. But I want my array to look like:

```
myArray = [
  {"fname":"kevin", "lname":"albert"},
  {"fname":"albert", "lname":"kevin"},
  ...etc.
]
```

Source page script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#btn").click(function(){
                var obj=new Object();

                obj.fname=document.getElementById("fname").value;
                obj.mname=document.getElementById("mname").value;
                obj.lname=document.getElementById("lname").value;

                localStorage.setItem("object",JSON.stringify(obj));
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Destination page script:

```
var myArray=[];

    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("hello");
        myArray.push(localStorage.getItem("object"));

        $("#btn2").click(function(){

            document.getElementById("here").innerHTML=myArray;
            return false;
        });
});
```

Comment: make your "myArray" globbaly, else every time it will create new one

Comment: you could set the array to local storage, and every time you update it, you could retrieve it, push the new object and assign it back to the local storage key that was used

Comment: @Vishalmodi i have already declared myArray globally.. thank you!

Comment: @shrys my question is how do i create a new object each time?

Comment: you are already doing that in `source page script`, instead of assigning `obj` to `object` key assign `myArray` after pushing the new object into it

Comment: @shrys  do i want to store the array in local storage and push values into it??  or after pushing elements into array store it in local storage??

Comment: yes, get array from localStorage, push new value into array, store the new array back to localStorage. in this order

Comment: @shrys ok bro... i'll try!

Comment: if myArray is global why would you define it again in the second page script?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get and set the all objects into the localstorage like so:

```js
var myArray = (localStorage.getItem("objects")) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("objects")) : [];


$(document).ready(function(){
    //alert("hello");
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        document.getElementById("here").innerHTML=JSON.stringify(myArray);
        return false;
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        var obj=new Object();

        obj.fname=document.getElementById("fname").value;
        obj.mname=document.getElementById("mname").value;
        obj.lname=document.getElementById("lname").value;
        
        myArray.push(obj);

        localStorage.setItem("objects",JSON.stringify(myArray));
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the original array from the local storage first, then add the new object, then save it back to the local storage. Something like the code below should help.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").click(function(){

    let objList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("object")) || []; // read from localstorage
    let obj = new Object(); // create new object

    obj.fname=document.getElementById("fname").value; // add values to new object
    obj.mname=document.getElementById("mname").value;
    obj.lname=document.getElementById("lname").value;

    objList.push(obj); // push new object to objectList

    localStorage.setItem("object",JSON.stringify(objList)); // save objectList in localstorage
    return false;
  });
});
```